# .php pages not working on xampp

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I'm running xampp version 2.5 on windows 7 and ftp'd over a website I'm working on ([www.dfwcertautos.com](http://www.dfwcertautos.com)). None of the .php pages load, however the .html pages load fine. I created a test.php page with "hello world" and it loaded correctly. Any suggestions for getting it to run properly? The site has no database, however it does have an XML feed coming in to it from another service. I didn't make any changes to the htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

What FTP client did You use?

It is possible that when copying the files in "Text" and not "Binary" mode there was a special whitespace added on the beginning of each PHP file so the PHP file cannot be executed on APACHE server...

EDIT: another idea - aren't You using PHP short tags `<?` instead of `<?php` on Your localhost while on the server the short opening tag (`<?`) is not permitted...?

Comment: I used filezilla - I just tried copying everything over in Binary mode and no change. I checked and nothing is short tagged, so that's not it either. I believe if it was short-tagged it would have displayed a break in code at a certain line. This is the page load error I get :The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost/dfw/index.php. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly.